# When uploading an image (jpeg, gif file etc) using WebDAV can I select which multimedia schema is used?

Tags: webdav, multimedia

When uploading an image using WebDAV, Tridion creates a multimedia component matching the folder's linked schema or the Default Multimedia Schema.

Is it possible to instead select which multimedia schema Tridion uses when creating a multimedia component from an image uploaded using WebDAV?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Check out this article, http://elenaserghie.blogspot.com/2012/03/uploading-multimedia-items-with-sdl.html

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange. I have edited your question somewhat to hopefully clarify what you are asking. If there are any issues with my changes please feel free to revert or edit them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are uploading images to an existing `Folder` you can specify a schema for that folder in the CME, after it any image uploaded using `Webdav` in that folder will use the specified schema.

Additionally you can use an event system to execute some code in the `Save-Initiated` event in order to select the multimedia schema, it will give you more control but there is development involved here.

Answer (score 2):

Given that webdav is "just" a protocol, implementation of anything that is specific to a server (Tridion in this case) would require a custom client-side UI for this.

This means that the answer to your question is "No".

You can however control which schema will be used by setting:

- A default schema in your Publication
- A specific schema as mandatory on a given folder to override publication default

There *might* be something you can do at the Event System level too, but I strongly doubt you'd be able to determine which client was used from the Tridion core (we are adding this functionality but it requires that clients identify themselves).

Comment: WebDav protocol identifies itself since last release. TcmApplicationId.WebDav with value "tcm:WebDav" is set to Session context data.

Comment: Awesome! So you could do something in the Event System that would only trigger if current item is being created from Webdav (as from 2013)