# Is there any way to determine from an event system and/or a template whether it is being called from Experience Manager or somewhere else?

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, templating, event-system

I am trying to identify in my Event System and in my Templates when the rendering (template) or the action (event system) is being triggered from either Experience Manager or somewhere else in the system. The reason being I don't want some Events to execute if the user is doing inline editing or adding a component to a page from Experience Manager.

In the same way, I want my template to behave differently if the rendering is taking place in Experience Manager (I know this question might have been asked already, but can't find it)

I know that the `RenderMode` will tell me something, but I now it doesn't always tell you the "truth".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if publishing to SiteEditable/XPM-enabled site?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2171/how-to-determine-if-publishing-to-siteeditable-xpm-enabled-site)

Comment: Different question Nick. You wanted to identify if you were publishing to a XPM-enabled target. Jaime wants to identify if the current render action is due to Session Preview activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify if you code is being called from Experience Manager in your templates by checking the Render Mode and the Publication Target, if the Render Mode is Dynamic and the Publication Target is not null then your template is being called from Experience Manager.

Comment: Wouldn't that be true as well when publishing?

Comment: Render Mode is Publish when we publish if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Well, but isn't oData "Publishing" too? Or the Publisher sets the mode as "Dynamic" instead?

Comment: No, it's previewing.

Comment: And Eric, you're right. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14642317/866454

Comment: Don't forget to scroll up and upvote the original question that answer is attached to. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Tridion 2013 we introduced a way for clients to identify themselves to the core, and this information can be retrieved from the Event System. See [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3001/33)'s comments to see how Webdav identifies itself. I do not know if Experience Manager already uses this relatively new feature, but it will in the future for sure.

In regards to how to determine this in the Template, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642317/866454) answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That second answer you mentioned (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14642317/866454) describes how to identify session preview and normal (both CME and XPM) publishing. I think what Jaime is looking for is to identify XPM rendering (either preview or publishing). We cannot identify XPM rendering with the PublicationTarget and RenderMode parameters.

Comment: So all our hopes are on TcmApplicationId from the first answer you mentioned (see http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3001/33). Did anyone try TcmApplicationId?

Comment: Jan, you _can_ identify XPM rendering. What you cannot is identify XPM was the source from the Event System.

Comment: Interesting information, will check it out.